# Remove focus color from select option in IE8

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the focus color from an option box when selected. 
When you select a date from the select box it shows a blue background color in IE. I want to remove this. It goes away if you deselect by clicking the page. somewhere else other than the select box.

I've tried below css but it's not working in IE8.

```
select option:focus{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do want them to see the selection they have made. I just don't want the blue color to stay selected behind the text in IE8 like the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

As w3school says:

Note: For :focus to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Any reproducible code in a fiddle please?

Do you test in a VM IE8 (great) or IE9/10 as IE8 (don't)?

Did you try with `:active` instead of `:focus` (but I think it's a problem with IE7-, not IE8)

What about:

```
option:focus {
    background-color: inherit !important;
}
```